# SwiftUI View: Int/Double is not convertible to CGFloat

Tags: swiftui

With the following SwiftUI view, I get the compiler error "Int is not convertible to CGFloat" on the line calling `padding()`. If I change the value passed to `padding()` to 50.0, it says "Double is not convertible to CGFloat".

```
struct TitleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("What the fuck")
                        .font(Font.custom("Rochester-Regular", size:60))
                    Text("Date Today 07, 21 99").foregroundColor(Color("fontColor")).padding(.bottom, 50)
                    HStack {
                        Image("icons8-refresh-24")
                        Image("icons8-pause-26")
                        Button(action : {
                            NavigationLink(destination:SceneView())
                        }) {
                            Image("icons8-play-26").renderingMode(.original)
                        }
                    }.padding(.top, 50) // error is received here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TitleView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TitleView()
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI is very new, and the compiler gives incorrect errors. Comment out different lines to narrow down the issue until you locate the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your navigation line isn't a valid syntax use

```
struct TitleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("What").font(Font.custom("Rochester-Regular",size:60.0))
                Text("Date Today 07, 21 99").foregroundColor(Color("fontColor")).padding(.bottom, CGFloat(50.0))
                HStack {
                        Image("icons8-refresh-24")
                        Image("icons8-pause-26")
                        Button(action : {
                            NavigationLink("", destination: SceneView())
                        }) {
                            Image("icons8-play-26").renderingMode(.original)
                        }
                }.padding(.top,50)
            }
        }
    }
}
```